# JAVA NoClassDefFoundError on external jar library

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an `Android` app in `JAVA` using [this](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library for formatting phone numbers.
I am receiving the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil;
```

Here:

```
public class InvocationTargetException extends ReflectiveOperationException  {
...
public InvocationTargetException(Throwable exception) {
    super(null, exception);
    target = exception;
}
...
}
```

When executing the command:

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
```

I have imported the `com.google.i18n.phonenumbers` lib, but I cant figure out what is the `L` in the exception description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L` is added for internal JVM `objectype` representation, but it is actually looking for `com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil` class.

It seems the library is missing in your `Runtime classpath`.

[Field Descriptions Documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3)

Comment: It was a problem with some duplicate jars.. Had to remove all the jars and clean the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jar file to your class path? Are you using Android Studio? In that case you can add the entry to the app/build.gradle file.

Comment: I am using eclipse and the jar indeed is in my classpath. The project is compiling just fine